# C++ placement new keep giving compiling error

Tags: c++

Try to use placement new but it kept giving me errors. I remember a while ago, it was working.   g++ (ver 4.8.4) on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;
struct strSession {
    uint   sessionId;
    uint   srcIp;
    uint   dstIp;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[20];
    strSession *q = (strSession*)&buf[0]; 
    new (q) strSession;
    return 0;
}
```

Got error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te.cc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
te.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te.cc:12:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new(sizetype, strSession*&)’
  new (q) strSession;
          ^
te.cc:12:10: note: candidate is:
<built-in>:0:0: note: void* operator new(long unsigned int)
<built-in>:0:0: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use placement `new`, you need to have:

```
#include <new>
```

Also, you could just as easily have used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[20];
    strSession *q = new (buf) strSession;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also I don't quite get the point of `q`. Seems to defeat the object. Haha, so to speak.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, agree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I must admit I don't understand how placement `new` and alignment work together. There is no guarantee that the pointer passed to placement will meet the alignment requirements of the object type.

Comment: Indeed. There's some standard library magic to make it work but I am as in the dark as you. I just know it exists :)

Comment: Something about `std::aligned_storage` but 30 seconds searching SO reveals no evidence why it's necessary. Sigh who knows. C++ is stupid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. Yes, the `q` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

To make your original code work, you need to add

```
void* operator new( size_t, strSession * p ) { return p; }
```

In the old days, before C++ left Bell Labs, C++ had a feature where
a constructor could assign to 'this'.  The operator new placement
syntax was considered an improvement.